# Apache proxy_http:error 502

Tags: apache, redirect, reverse-proxy

I am using Apache httpd as a proxy server where I am redirecting, the authentication to SSO server (ADFS), while redirecting I am getting this error :

[proxy_http:error] [pid 105663:tid 139669754791680] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client ********] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server adfs-server-name:443, referer: https://hostname/

Any help is highly appreciated !!!

Thanks,
Soubhagya

Answer (score 1):

We figured out the issue ,we were having with our proxy server redirects to ADFS server.

It was due to one of the property “ProxyPreserveHost” on our Apache httpd, which due to Http/2  standard was trying to reuse the connection , but when Apache gets request from the same domain with multiple headers it gets confused and throws 421 (Misdirected request error) which was not quite visible ,I guess the mod_proxy module was wrapping it in 502 for the proxypass and throwing it back to browser (which was making it confusing as if the upstream server which is ADFS is throwing the error or not responding). I am still trying to figure out what causes this different header’s being sent during different request’s which leads to error code 421 or is it something else.